# Spinner Perzonalizado Problema de ancho

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo este spinner con un adapter perzonalizado , pero el tema es que no estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado , en este momento se ve asi ,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia tengo 2 flechas , una es de mi layout personalizado  , y la otra es la que trae el spinner ,

Este es mi Layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:background="@drawable/redondo"
android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/flechaabajooo"/>
```

Y asi lo seteo

```
Spinner tipodePerfilSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SprTipoPerfil);

    ArrayList<String> Tipos = new ArrayList<>();
    Tipos.add("Persona");
    final  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InformationsPersonal.this,R.layout.spinner_custom,R.id.text1,Tipos);
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_custom);
    tipodePerfilSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);

    tipodePerfilSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object tipo = dataAdapter2.getItem(position);
            TipoSeleccionado = tipo.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
            //TODO implementar
        }

    });
```

La verdad me quede sin ideas de porque no ocupa todo el ancho si tiene `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

aparte de que tampoco se centra cosa que deberia.

o como sacarle la flecha que trae por defecto el spinner , cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida , desde ya gracias

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres imitar el estilo de un spinner con un TextView?

Comment: prueba con fill_parent en vez de match_parent a la hora de definir el ancho de tu layout

Comment: @Einer Si mi problema es que el fondo oscuro no tapa la flecha que trae por defecto el spinner, me gustaria que la tapara

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano  sige igual !

Comment: una duda, estas intentando dar un "estilo" a un textview y se lo estás aplicando a un spinner???

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano ahmm es el layout perzonalizado que le paso al Adapter del spinner si , intente hacerlo asi , si hay una forma mas reconfortante de hacerlo la verdad no lo encontre .. esto no lo invente yo ivestige por aqui el foro y fue lo mejorcito que salio ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estas utilizando el estilo `style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"` te aparece el estilo del spinner y ademas tambien le estas agregando otra fecha a tu TextView `android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/flechaabajooo"/>`.

Si lo que quieres es imitar el estilo de un Spinner, crea un archivo llamado `spinner_like.xml` en la carpeta `drawnable` con lo siguiente:

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ccc" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#ccc" />
</shape>
```

Entonces a tu `TextView` lo cambiarias asi:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_like"
android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/flechaabajooo"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Einer , Siempre tan atento  y dedicado en las respuestas !